# Hibernate @AttributeOverride with @ColumnTransformer

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm studying Hibernate/JPA and doing some practice to. So my task is to map this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "priceInUSD", column = @Column(name = "start_price_in_uah"))
    private Price startPrice;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "priceInUSD", column = @Column(name = "end_price_in_uah"))
    private Price endPrice;
}
```

And here is my embeddable class:

```
@Embeddable
public class Price {
    @Column(name = "price_in_uah")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer(
            read = "{dont_know_what_to_put_here} * 0.039",
            write = "? / 0.039")
    private int priceInUSD;
}
```

In my DB I store the price in **UAH** and in my Java code I have it in **USD**.
I understand that this is a bit stupid example, but still...

The problem is when I use hibernate's `@ColumnTransformer` where I have to specify the column name in the `read` property (like "price_in_uah * 0.039"), but because of the `@AttributeOverride` annotation, the column
name can change.

So, what can I put instead of the `{dont_know_what_to_put_here}` label?

Comment: Because exchange rate changes in time, strongly suggest different solution. Hard to repair DB design problem in Entity (I'm surprised 'int' too)

Comment: BTW formal suggest (maybe in next projects) use portable JPA to maximum possible level

Comment: Yes, I should propably try another solution. I was curious if you can somehow specify the column name.

Comment: And using 'int' to store 'money' was a recomendation from my friend. Yes, multipliying it by '0.039' looks strange. But that is not a real project. I'm just trying hibernate's '@ColumnTransformer' feature